# How to migrate crm 2011 activities?

Tags: migration, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

i have two systems Microsoft crm 2011 with one windows live id and another with the office 365 , which I intend to migrate data from one to the other, but stumbled when trying to migrate the activities, and the most important are calls, appointment and tasks. I know the solution Scribes, but the company is not willing to pay! Any other ideia?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. Activities are just another record type (multiple types) in CRM so if you have a way of taking any record type from crm1 and inserting into crm2, it should work for activities. Are you asking about migration of data between crms in general?

Comment: I already solved the problem using the solution "data sync studio 3", the problem is to migrate the activities without losing the relationships with the entities. Exporting to excell you will lose the relationships.

Comment: each activity record has a field that contains the guid of the record the activity is associated with. i am not familiar with data sync studio 3 but if it grabs the whole activity record, it should preserve the link to the parent record so to speak

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transfer Activities with their relationships you can do this by using [Scribe](http://www.scribesoft.com/). You can set up links between your old system and current, and add as many steps as you need to ensure that the data is transferred over appropriately.